Save other data along with GeoJSON
I am wondering about how to save data like time, heart rate, temperature, etc. along with a GeoJSON LINESTRING in MongoDB. I am going to run optimization on the LINESTRING, like simplification with the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm. So points from the original LINESTRING will be missing, therefore I am afraid keeping the other data in a separate array will make it hard to keep the connection between each coordinate and the additional data since the indexes won't be the same. Also points might be edited by the user, or snapped to map data ...
The LINESTRING data should be able to be queried fast to render it on web maps. The other data should be queried for analyses, e.g when mouse over the track, the corresponding data should be shown. Mouse over a chart with the data, should show the corresponding point of the route in the track ...
I can think of three ways to do it

Multiple arrays

    add_data: { 
      temperature: [10, 10, 11, 11],
      heart_rate: [112, 115, 118, 117],
      time: [1734505372, 1734505432, 1734505492, 1734505552]}
    route: { 
      type: LINESTRING, 
      coordinates: [
                [-4.4214296,36.73835],
                [-4.422104,36.737865],
                [-4.4229302,36.73773],
                [-4.4235334,36.735817],
              ]
             }


Point (MULTIPOINT ?) objects with all data

[
   { point: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 10, heart_rate: 112, time: 1734505372},
   { point: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 10, heart_rate: 115, time: 1734505432}
   { point: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 11, heart_rate: 118, time: 1734505492}
   { point: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 11, heart_rate: 117, time: 1734505552}
]


A combination of 1 and 2

route: { 
  type: LINESTRING, 
  coordinates: [
            [-4.4214296,36.73835],
            [-4.422104,36.737865],
            [-4.4229302,36.73773],
            [-4.4235334,36.735817],
          ]
         }

add_data: [
   { coordinate: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 10, heart_rate: 112, time: 1734505372},
   { coordinate: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 10, heart_rate: 115, time: 1734505432}
   { coordinate: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 11, heart_rate: 118, time: 1734505492}
   { coordinate: [-4.4214296,36.73835], temperature: 11, heart_rate: 117, time: 1734505552}
]

In case 2 I guess i couldn't utilize the geospatial features of MongoDB since the GeoJSON format is lost. But in case 1 I am afraid I am going to loose the connection between coordinate and additional data. Especially when the data might be edited, points removed.
In case 3 I have the GeoJson to perform geospatial operations, and query additional data by the coordinate. But coordinates might be the same going forth and back the same way, or if the route is snapped to map data...
What might be the best, is there a better way to do it? Other database like PostgreSQL?

What about case 2 with point specified as GeoJSON point: {point: {type: "Point", coordinates: [-4.4214296,36.73835]}, temperature: 10, heart_rate: 112, time: 1734505372}?

This would be a MultiPoint geometry? I have no experience with this geometry type yet, but I guess I couldn't apply the same geospatial features to it like line simplification, rendering a line, ...

Not, this is not multipoint geometry, it's on array of JSON objects, where each object has point geometry. I'm not familiar with MongoDB, so this was just a suggestion what you could try.

In a relational database design (eg PostgreSQL, MySQL), everything is in tables (which is what  "relations" are).
So you'd have a table of points, where each point would have its location, any other attributes of an individual line (like sampling time, height, land cover class etc etc), and of course a unique point identifier.
Then you have a line table storing info about the lines as whole features, maybe the name of the person who ran that line, and a unique line identifier.
Then there's a table that tells you which points make the lines. This would have columns of line id, point id, and point_order. These should be uniquely identifiable by the tuple (line id, point id) so don't really need their own id column. You can then construct line features by joining the line-point table to the points, grouping by line id, ordering by point_order, and so on.
The usual "simple features" model for spatial data implemented in most spatial databases (eg PostGIS) doesn't implement the slightly more complex data model you have, where both points and lines that connect them have individual attributes, so it might be necessary to implement this as I've described. You'd use the POINT geometry for your point table, and write some SQL functions to create LINE geometry objects from joining and grouping the tables. You could use a VIEW for this so that you effectively have a table of LINE objects but its dynamically created from whatever the current state of the POINT table is.
The "Simple Features" model does allow two extra pieces of data at each point of a LINE or POLYGON boundary, called Z and M. Z is meant to be used for height and M is some single "Measure" at the vertex. I suppose you could use this as an index to link to another table, but its rare that I've ever seen it used for anything.
